# Permissions to Create DB's and be able to perform any function only on those DB's

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, permissions

I am looking for a way to allow users to create databases which only they and SA accounts will have access to (Perform any function; creating/deleteing tables, deleting the DB, etc).

For example, User1 creates DB1 and User2 creates DB2. User1 must have full access to DB1 but no access to DB2 and User2 will have full access to DB2 but no access to DB1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to clear up the distinction between *logins* (security entities at the server level) and *users* (security entities at the database level, which may be associated with a server-level login).

What you want to do here is grant `CREATE ANY DATABASE` to the server-level login. For example:

```
CREATE LOGIN foo WITH PASSWORD = N'bar', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
GO
GRANT CREATE ANY DATABASE TO foo;
GO
```

Now, log in as `foo` in another window, and note that they can do this:

```
CREATE DATABASE foo_1;
GO
USE foo_1;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.bar_1(foo_what INT);
GO
```

But as soon as they try to use a database they did not create:

```
USE AdventureWorks2014;
GO
```

They are blocked:

> Msg 916, Level 14, State 1
>   
> The server principal "foo" is not able to access the database "AdventureWorks2014" under the current security context.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not clued up on SQL, but have been tasked with watching over that server till we get a DBA. Hoping your solution will do the trick, but will check when I am back at work. It looks like you did test the command and the result looks good, so will mark your answer as the solution. Out of curiousity, what does the CHECK_POLICY affect. Thank you

Comment: @David `CHECK_POLICY` just allows me to create a login with a very simple password for you to test - it prevents SQL Server from checking the underlying strong password rules, which allows me to not have to figure out what your organization's strong password rules are in order to generate a fake password for a test login that passes the check.